# Reset meteor deploy password

Tags: deployment, meteor

Is there any way to reset a meteor password if I lose the password? If someone finds out a password I'm using will I be able to recover my site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is not very intuitive as the command-line meteor help login tells you nothing.

You can go here:
`https://www.meteor.com/account-settings`

click `sign in` in the upper right. Click `forgot password`!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteordeploy):

> You can change the password by running meteor deploy --password again, which will first prompt for the current password, then for a new password.

As for your second question, you'll always be able to re-deploy your local version of the site.

Comment: Thank you justswim. I missed a part in the question, what I meant to ask was if I could reset the password if I forgot it. I edited the  question to reflect that. I know if I backup the DB I can redeploy it somewhere else, but will I be blocked forver for that domain on the meteor.com site? Thanks!